# Rails: Add error message through model to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So far I understood that you only can raise error messages in the controller. The Sale model is a child of the Order model. So I did this:

```
class SalesController < ApplicationController
 def create
  ...
  if @sale.errors.any?
   flash[:error] = "#{@order.sale.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}"
  end
 end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save :discount

def discount=(discount)
 if discount.present?
  if current_user.maxdiscount >= discount.to_d
    discount = discount.gsub(",", ".")
    self[:discount] = discount
  else
    self.errors.add(:discount, "The discount is too high. The product was added without it.")
  end
 end
end
```

But that does not work. The main goal is to raise an error message whenever a user tries to submit a value that is bigger than the `current_user.maxdiscount`.

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can record error messages at Model level.

But as you do it in callback, you have to stop the transaction by returning `false` or raise an error manually.

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_save :discount

   def discount=(discount)
     if discount.present?
      if current_user.maxdiscount >= discount.to_d
        discount = discount.gsub(",", ".")
        self[:discount] = discount
      else
        self.errors.add(:discount, "The discount is too high. The product was added without it.")
        return false
      end
   end
end
```